# Why's my GET request not accessible when trying to pass a variable down from top most level component into Route component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I know this is a timing issue but for some reason, I'm not able to access the response inside `App` and `Gallery` components.  I see the response in the `console.log()`s but they're not accessible.  They each have that blue `i` depicted in the screenshot below.

[image]

The order of those from which components they're being fired as follows `console.log()`s are follows: `Gallery`, `App`, `App`, `Gallery`, `Gallery`

Inside `App` component, I've tried to put the `getUploads()` function inside `useEffect()` but that gives me the same results.

What I want is for the response to fire once in `App.js` and subsequently be accessible in the `Gallery` component once and once only but I'm having trouble understanding and rectifying this issue.

Here's `App` component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../../sass/HomePage/homePage.scss';
import LoginRegister from "./LoginRegister/LoginRegister";
import Gallery from "./Gallery/Gallery";

const App = () => {
    const [uploadsData, setUploadsData] = useState([]);
    let { push } = useHistory();
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');

    useEffect(() => {
        getUploads();
    }, [push, authToken]);

    const getUploads = () => {
        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
        }

        axios.get('http://localhost:8005/api/get-uploads', {headers})
            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp);
                console.log(uploadsData)
                if (authToken !== null) {
                    setUploadsData([resp]);
                    push('/gallery');
                } else {
                    push('/');
                }
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={LoginRegister} />
                <Route exact path="/gallery" component={() => <Gallery data={uploadsData}/>} />
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Router><App/></Router>, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

Here's `Gallery` component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Gallery = (data) => {    
    return (
        <>    
            {console.log(data)}
        </>
    );
}

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: setUploadsData is async, most likely you are switching to the gallery route before the App rerenders due to the setUploadsData call.

Comment: localStorage.getItem('token') is going to run every time the component redners. It should be internalized to getUploads.

Comment: @windowsill is it cool if you can demonstrate what you mean using my code? Sorry, I've been stuck on this for so long that I've exhausted almost every possible way that I thought would fix this :(

Comment: Since your gallery component doesn't do anything it's reallly hard to see what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @windowsill I just want it to fire once and also be accessible in Gallery component.  Not sure why it's firing multiple times and not accessible.

Comment: I've written the reason in the first comment. Calling setUploadsData schedules a re-render with the new state, it doesn't immediately update the state. Your gallery component should be reactive anyway, ie, it shouldn't matter which props are available or when, it should render some JSX for any situation.